# Creating an Enter to "try again" with password validation

Tags: java

so my main issue is i want to create a way for anyone using this project to restart the program when they hit enter, i would prefer if this was only an option for if their password didnt follow the guidelines i have set but i will settle for just restarting the program by hitting enter at the end. Sorry if the format of the post isnt great, this is my first time using this site.

```
//This Java program will provide the user with the ability to test the strength of their password against numerous criteria set within the program.
//The program will scan the inputed password to make sure that it follows the guidelines and will project whether or not the password meets the requirements.

import java.util.Scanner;//Scanner input for future use,explained in detail further down the code
public class MainPassword {
    public static void main(String args[]) //Main method of the password validation program
    {
        Scanner PasswordValidation = new Scanner(System.in);//Scanner is used for scanning input that the user enters
        System.out.println("\r\n"
                + "██████╗░░█████╗░░██████╗░██████╗░██╗░░░░░░░██╗░█████╗░██████╗░██████╗░\r\n"
                + "██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝██╔════╝░██║░░██╗░░██║██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔══██╗\r\n"
                + "██████╔╝███████║╚█████╗░╚█████╗░░╚██╗████╗██╔╝██║░░██║██████╔╝██║░░██║\r\n"
                + "██╔═══╝░██╔══██║░╚═══██╗░╚═══██╗░░████╔═████║░██║░░██║██╔══██╗██║░░██║\r\n"
                + "██║░░░░░██║░░██║██████╔╝██████╔╝░░╚██╔╝░╚██╔╝░╚█████╔╝██║░░██║██████╔╝\r\n"
                + "╚═╝░░░░░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═════╝░╚═════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═════╝░\r\n"
                + "\r\n"
                + "██╗░░░██╗░█████╗░██╗░░░░░██╗██████╗░░█████╗░████████╗░█████╗░██████╗░\r\n"
                + "██║░░░██║██╔══██╗██║░░░░░██║██╔══██╗██╔══██╗╚══██╔══╝██╔══██╗██╔══██╗\r\n"
                + "╚██╗░██╔╝███████║██║░░░░░██║██║░░██║███████║░░░██║░░░██║░░██║██████╔╝\r\n"
                + "░╚████╔╝░██╔══██║██║░░░░░██║██║░░██║██╔══██║░░░██║░░░██║░░██║██╔══██╗\r\n"
                + "░░╚██╔╝░░██║░░██║███████╗██║██████╔╝██║░░██║░░░██║░░░╚█████╔╝██║░░██║\r\n"
                + "░░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚══════╝╚═╝╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░░░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝");
        System.out.println("  ");
        System.out.println("Welcome to Password Validator, please ensure to adhere to the following guidelines:");
        System.out.println("  ");
        System.out.println("Ensure that the password is 8 to 5 characters long");
        System.out.println("  ");
        System.out.println("Ensure that the password contains atleast two capital letters");
        System.out.println("  ");
        System.out.println("Ensure that the password contrains atleast two numbers");
        System.out.println("  ");
        System.out.print("Please enter your new password: ");
        String str = PasswordValidation.nextLine();
        
        boolean isValid = true;
        boolean length = false;
        boolean isUpper = false;
        boolean hasDigit = false;
        
        
        if(str.length() >= 8)
            length = true;
        if(str.length() >= 16)
            length = false;
        
        for(int i=2; i<str.length(); i++)
        {
            if(Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i)))
                isUpper = true;
        }
        for(int i=2; i<str.length(); i++)
        {
            if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))
                hasDigit = true;
        }
        if(length && isUpper && hasDigit)
            System.out.println("  " + " " + "\n\r\n"
                    + "░█████╗░░█████╗░███╗░░██╗░██████╗░██████╗░░█████╗░████████╗██╗░░░██╗██╗░░░░░████████╗██╗░█████╗░███╗░░██╗░██████╗\r\n"
                    + "██╔══██╗██╔══██╗████╗░██║██╔════╝░██╔══██╗██╔══██╗╚══██╔══╝██║░░░██║██║░░░░░╚══██╔══╝██║██╔══██╗████╗░██║██╔════╝\r\n"
                    + "██║░░╚═╝██║░░██║██╔██╗██║██║░░██╗░██████╔╝███████║░░░██║░░░██║░░░██║██║░░░░░░░░██║░░░██║██║░░██║██╔██╗██║╚█████╗░\r\n"
                    + "██║░░██╗██║░░██║██║╚████║██║░░╚██╗██╔══██╗██╔══██║░░░██║░░░██║░░░██║██║░░░░░░░░██║░░░██║██║░░██║██║╚████║░╚═══██╗\r\n"
                    + "╚█████╔╝╚█████╔╝██║░╚███║╚██████╔╝██║░░██║██║░░██║░░░██║░░░╚██████╔╝███████╗░░░██║░░░██║╚█████╔╝██║░╚███║██████╔╝\r\n"
                    + "░╚════╝░░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚══╝░╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░░░╚═════╝░╚══════╝░░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚══╝╚═════╝░" + "\nYour Password is valid");
        else
            System.out.println("██╗░░░██╗██╗░░██╗  ░█████╗░██╗░░██╗██╗\r\n"
                    + "██║░░░██║██║░░██║  ██╔══██╗██║░░██║██║\r\n"
                    + "██║░░░██║███████║  ██║░░██║███████║██║\r\n"
                    + "██║░░░██║██╔══██║  ██║░░██║██╔══██║╚═╝\r\n"
                    + "╚██████╔╝██║░░██║  ╚█████╔╝██║░░██║██╗\r\n"
                    + "░╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝  ░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝" + "\nYour password is invalid");
        if(str.length() < 8)
            System.out.println("Password is shorter than 8 characters in length");
        else if(str.length() > 15)
        System.out.println("Password is longer than 15 characters in length");
        if(hasDigit !=true)
            System.out.println("Please ensure at least two Numbers are within the password");
        if(isUpper !=true)
            System.out.println("Please ensure at least two capital letters are within the password");
        while(isValid = false)
        {
            if(length && isUpper && hasDigit);
            System.out.println("Please press enter to try again");
            if(str == "");
            break;
            
        }
        
        PasswordValidation.close();
        
            
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider whether all this code is really necessary for a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You should work on only including relevant information.

The simplest way to do this is to have a loop.

```
boolean valid = false;
Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
while( !valid ){
    System.out.println("Enter password: ");
    String attempt = inp.readLine();
    
    //validate
    if( attempt.length() > 6 ){
        valid = true;
    } else{
        //don't do anything, valid is false so the loop will start over.
    }
    
}
```

You should be able to wrap the code you have inside of a similar loop. Your loop doesn't show the screen again, or request new input.

- Get the input
- Validate the input
- If it is valid, end the loop. Otherwise start over.